# evaluate one variable in an expression with two variables

Tags: r, expression, eval

I want to evaluate f with the mean=7

```
 mean=7
 f <-  expression(-(x-mean)^2/2)
```

then get a new expression:

```
 -(x-7)^2/2
```

How could I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `gsub`?

```
avg <- 7
f <- expression(-(x-avg)^2/2)
f.new <- as.expression(gsub('avg',avg,f))

expression("-(x - 7)^2/2")
```

on a side note, you should avoid defining variables with names like `mean` or `data` since they are built in `R` functions.

Comment: Thanks. My expression is very long, and there are lots of variables. I will try your method.

Comment: I think @JoshO'Brien has a better approach. But if you use `gsub`, ensure the string you are replacing is unique and not a sub-string of something else.

Comment: @Tommy (+1 to Josh) I'd be inclined to agree.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

```
f <- as.call(f)
eval(substitute(substitute(expr, list(mean=7)), list(expr= f)))
# -(x - 7)^2/2()
```

If that construction feels mind-bending, you don't need to feel alone: even the guys who wrote the R manual call the problem you've posed here ["a puzzle"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Substitutions).

Comment: +1 Nice use of substitute twice. But `f<-quote(-(x-mean)^2/2))` is probably a better way of specifying the expression... `as.call` won't work on `expression(mean)`...

Comment: @Tommy -- Yeah, I thought of making that suggestion, and am glad you brought it up here in comments.  I figured that even what's up there is a ton to chew on.  It feels like a koan to me -- short, pithy, and still rewarding after hours of contemplation.  I don't yet get why `f` needs to be a call rather than an expression, so I guess I'm not quite "there" yet ;)

Answer (score 0):

In S-Plus, the `substitute` function has an extra `evaluate` argument, so there it is rather easy. Unfortunately, R is missing that argument...

```
# in S-Plus:
x <- expression(-(x-mean)^2/2)
substitute(x, list(mean=7), evaluate=TRUE)
#-(x - 7)^2/2
```

...so you must resort to something like what @JoshO'Brien suggests. Consider logging this as a feature request with R core ;-)